# Jetbrains adding Closure as an external library

Tags: javascript, pycharm

I am trying to add Closure as an external library in PyCharm.

These lines demonstrate where I installed closure:

```
Chriss-MacBook-Pro:closure chris$ pwd
/Users/chris/DevLibrary/closure-library/closure
Chriss-MacBook-Pro:closure chris$ ls
bin     css     goog        known_issues
```

I've tried adding various directories in the edit libraries dialog such as:

```
/Users/chris/DevLibrary/closure-library/
/Users/chris/DevLibrary/closure-library/closure
/Users/chris/DevLibrary/closure-library/closure/goog
```

I've also tried adding the individual files.

But every time my File Watcher runs I still get:

> java -jar /Users/chris/Projects/housemaps/compiler.jar
>   --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js housemap.js housemap.js:1: ERROR - required "goog.dom" namespace never provided
>   goog.require('goog.dom'); ^
>
> 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The external libraries feature of Jetbrains is for providing your IDE with access to the source code (for code completion, error checking, ect) for Javascript files that are not included with your project, but are going to be hosted externally.

Closure is not designed to be hosted externally as it is supposed to be used with the closure compiler.